# Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I tried to use StanfordSegmenter to segment a piece of Chinese but encountered the captioned problem. I first downloaded Stanford Word Segmenter version 3.5.2 from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml

Then I wrote a python:

```
import os
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe"
from nltk.tokenize.stanford_segmenter import StanfordSegmenter
segmenter = StanfordSegmenter(path_to_jar = "./stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09/stanford-segmenter-3.6.0.jar", 
                          path_to_slf4j = "./stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09/slf4j-api.jar",
                          path_to_sihan_corpora_dict = "./stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09/data",
                          path_to_model = "./stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09/data/pku.gz", 
                          path_to_dict = "./stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09/data/dict-chris6.ser.gz")
sentence = u"这是斯坦福中文分词器测试"
segmenter.segment(sentence)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier
```

Where did I make mistakes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some implementation error. I too had the similar problem.
To resolve the error, just try doing

**segmenter._stanford_jar="./stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09/stanford-segmenter-3.6.0.jar"**

If this doesn't work trying giving full path of segementer jar file on segmenter._stanford_jar